# select query in MySQL NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am making search route for property table where user can enter city, state, street_*address , minamount , max*_amount to search for different properties. My problem is if user only enter one or two fileds search should be filter by those field only. and if user does not enter any parameters, it should show every property.

```
const sqlQuery = `SELECT * FROM property WHERE state = ? AND city = ? AND street_address = ?  AND min_amount >= ? AND max_amount <= ?;  `
  const values = [req.body.state, req.body.city, req.body.street_address ,req.body.min_amount,req.body.max_amount];
  let data = [];
  db.query (sqlQuery, values, function (err, results, fields) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    if (results.length >= 1) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct your `sqlQuery` manually by checking the existence of each parameter and appending a corresponding `WHERE` clause individually for each parameter, if this parameter exists.

Comment: if (req.body.state) {
    state = `state = '${req.body.state}' AND`;
  } else {
    state = ``;
  }  

const sqlQuery = `SELECT * FROM property WHERE isactive = 'Y' AND ${state}  ${city}  ${street_address}  ${min_amount}  ${max_amount} isactive = 'Y'  `;

Solved it by doing this